# Counting the number of rooted $m$-ary trees.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations, trees

I know that the Catalan number $C_n$ is the number of full (i.e., 0 or 2 children per node) binary trees with $n+1$ leaves. I am interested in the generalization.

Note that I do not care about any labeling, ordering, or number of leaves. I just want the tree to be rooted and have total number of nodes equal $n$, that's all. I am also not referring to a *full* $m$-ary tree, i.e., in my case nodes can have any number of children $\in\{0,\dots,m\}$ (instead of just 0 or $m$ in the full case). To summarize, my trees are rooted, unordered, unlabeled, $m$-ary, incomplete, not full, and have $n$ nodes in total.

With that being said, I would also like to point out the Fuss-Catalan numbers. From the Wiki page of "m-ary tree", it states that the total number of possible m-ary tree with n nodes is
\begin{align}
C_n=\frac{1}{(m-1)n+1}\cdot{mn\choose n}.
\end{align}
Does this hold for **non-full** $m$-ary trees? If so, why? Can I see a derivation of this result with relation to the tree. I've checked the book "Concrete Mathematics 2nd edition" (p. 361) but their derivation wasn't with regards to the trees but instead with $m$-Raney sequences (perhaps a strong link exists with trees). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have *Concrete Mathematics*, you know that the numbers $$C_n^{(m)}=\frac1{(m-1)n+1}\binom{mn}n$$ satisfy the recurrence

$$C_{n+1}^{(m)}=\sum_{\substack{0\le n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m\\n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_m=n}}C_{n_1}^{(m)}C_{n_2}^{(m)}\ldots C_{n_m}^{(m)}+[n=0]\;;$$

see the bottom of page $361$. The same induction argument that shows that the Catalan number $C_n=C_n^{(2)}$ is the number of full binary trees with $n$ internal nodes shows that $C_n^{(m)}$ is the number of full $m$-ary trees with $n$ internal nodes. Any $m$-ary plane tree with $n$ nodes can be extended to a full $m$-ary tree with $n$ internal nodes by adding a suitable number of leaf children to each node that does not have $m$ children. Conversely, any full $m$-ary tree with $n$ internal nodes can be reduced to an $m$-ary plane tree with $n$ nodes by deleting all of its leaves. These two operations are inverses, so each is a bijection between full $m$-ary trees with $n$ internal nodes and $m$-ary plane trees with $n$ nodes. Thus, $C_n^{(m)}$ is also the number of $m$-ary plane trees with $n$ nodes.

Note, however, that this is for **plane** trees, meaning that the children of each node **are** assumed to be linearly ordered, and changing the order changes the tree. The situation for unordered trees is *much* messier even without restrictions on the degrees of the nodes: see OEIS [$A000081$](https://oeis.org/A000081), for instance.

Comment: Thank you so much! Regarding your last paragraph, I want to clarify your **plane** definition. It is saying that for a given node with the some children, if I rearrange the order of the children (without changing the number of children), then it will give us a different order? Is that right? So in other words, I am asking if the Fuss-Catalan number can be used to give an upper bound on the number of unordered rooted $m$-ary tress -- which is my purpose.

Comment: @User: Yes, if you reorder the children of a node, of course letting them carry their descendants with them in the reordering, you have a different tree, unless the resulting trees are isomorphic taking order into account. That is, if for instance you swap two children that are the roots of isomorphic plane subtrees, you still have the same plane tree. So yes, this will give you an upper bound, as it distinguishes trees that you want to consider the same.

Comment: I think the mapping you stated, "adding a suitable number of leaf children to each node that does not have $m$ children," is *not* injective, because the number of children added cannot be recovered. Indeed, even though $C_2^{(3)}=3$, the number of $3$-ary plane trees with $2$ nodes is only $1$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Why do you think that it cannot be recovered? Any existing leaves at that node will have been extended and will no longer be leaves. **Every** leaf in the extended tree is new.

Comment: You are right, I was mistaken, but the numerical example I listed shows $C^{(m)}_n$ is not correct for this problem. I now think the problem is _deleting_ leaves is not injective, as [this example shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pn6r.png) (the image shows two full $2$-ary trees which, when their leaves are deleted, map to the same non-full $2$-ary tree).

Comment: @MikeEarnest: I count the two reduced trees as distinct: one has the left child of the root, and the other has the right child. My understanding of binary trees is that those are distinct positions even when only one is filled.

Comment: Ah, you and I had different interpretations of OP's problem. I was thinking that an ordered tree was a rooted tree where every vertex was given an ordering of its children, and an $m$-ary ordered tree was one where each node has at most $m$ children.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to count the number of **unordered**, unlabeled, $d$-ary, nonfull, rooted trees with $n$ vertices. As Brian's answer suggested, the **unordered** condition makes it unlikely for your problem to be tractable. However, it *is* possible to enumerate the number of trees satisfying all these conditions, but where "unordered" is replaced with "ordered."

**Edit:** I am defined an ordered tree to be "a rooted tree, together with an ordering of the children of each vertex," and a $d$-ary tree is one where every vertex has at most $d$ children. If you instead define an ordered $d$-ary tree to be a root vertex, together with a list of length $d$ where each entry is either empty or a subtree, then Brian's answer gives the correct enumeration.

This problem is best approached with generating functions. Let $t_n$ be the number of *ordered*, unlabeled, $d$-ary, nonfull, rooted trees with $n$ vertices, and let $T(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}t_nx^n$. Standard generating function trickery shows
$$
T(x)=x(1+T(x)+\dots+T(x)^d),
$$
since a tree consists of a root, followed by an ordered sequence consisting of between $0$ and $d$ subtrees. Writing this equation as
$$
x=\frac{T(1-T)}{1-T^{d+1}},
$$
we can see that $T(x)$ is the compositional inverse of $S(x)$, defined by
$$
S(x)=\frac{x(1-x)}{1-x^{d+1}}.
$$
Therefore, we can apply the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_Lagrange_inversion_formula) to compute $t_n$ in terms of the coefficients of $S(x)$. The LIF states that whenever $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are analytic functions for which $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $f'(0)g'(0)\neq 0$ and $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$, then the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are related by
$$
[x^n]g(x)^k=\frac{k}n[x^{-k}]f(x)^n\tag{LIF}
$$
Here, $[x^i]h(x)$ denotes the coefficient of $x^i$ in $h(x)$. Using this,
\begin{align}
t_n
  &=[x^n]T(x)
\\&\stackrel{\text{LIF}}=\tfrac1n[x^{-1}]S(x)^{-n}
\\&=\tfrac1n[x^{-1}]x^{-n}\left(\frac{1-x^{d+1}}{1-x}\right)^n
\\&=\tfrac1n[x^{n-1}](1-x^{d+1})^n(1-x)^{-n}
\\&=\boxed{\frac1n\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2-k(d+1)}{n-1-k(d+1)}.}
\end{align}